# Out of sample prediction from a list, specify list name to predict in R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, regression

I have a list of a large number of regression equations each separated in a list. Each list is assigned a key (a number). I would like to do an out of sample prediction that would match each set of sample data with the appropriate regression equation from that list.

Here is what I have so far and cannot seem to get it to work:

```
for (i in names(df_list)){

reg_predict = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(newdata, model) {
  data.frame(newdata, pred=predict(model,newdata))
}, df_list$`i`,reg_results2$`i`)))

}
```

df_list - contains list of variables I want to predict against, separated by key (number).

reg_results2 - contains list of my regression equations separated by key (number).

I even tried running this without the loop for just 1:

```
reg_predict = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(newdata, model) {
  data.frame(newdata, pred=predict(model,newdata))
}, df_list$`1`,reg_results2$`1`)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Thank you in advance for your help

df_list - how it looks:

1 (drop down arrow) - same thing for the others - 2,3,4,5,6, etc.:
contains variables as follows:

```
date   #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
y      #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
x1     #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
x2     #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
x3     #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
x4     #, #, #, #, #, #, ...
```

reg_results2 list:

1 (drop down arrow) - same thing for the others - 2,3,4,5,6, etc.:
contains variables as follows:

```
coefficients
residuals
effects
rank
fitted.values
assign
qr
df.residual
xlevels
call
terms
model
```

Reproducible example (TESTDATA):

```
Dates        Key NY     Tor    Chicago  Montreal
1-Jan-18     1  9073    8173    -5442   6786
2-Jan-18     1  4725    3790    -2814   -185
3-Jan-18     1  3447   -5471    -8821   5650
4-Jan-18     1  6320    9954    8804    -818
5-Jan-18     1  4757    6166    6156    -8059
6-Jan-18     1  5251    4922    6063    4517
7-Jan-18     1  4619   -8911    3256    -7389
8-Jan-18     1  8525   -8817    325     -1051
9-Jan-18     1  1955    3227    -206    -7664
10-Jan-18    1  5077    7551    9424    -6751
11-Jan-18    1  7595    1225    1406    7635
12-Jan-18    1  2682    1620    -5408   9743
13-Jan-18    1  8932   -3512    6341    9536
14-Jan-18    1  2354   -6192    -2665   3346
15-Jan-18    1  8557    5111    8375    2499
16-Jan-18    1  2087    -210    -982    6214
17-Jan-18    1  3212    -1252   951     5969
18-Jan-18    1  1131     711    -1102   4739
19-Jan-18    1  5493   -3580    -1600   4899
20-Jan-18    1  1940    9647    173    -4608
1-Jan-18     2  3231    3874    -1697   -39
2-Jan-18     2  -2608  -2082    3768    3978
3-Jan-18     2  -1     -3077    1884    -3503
4-Jan-18     2  -750    2987    -2822   1490
5-Jan-18     2  1305    1405    3658    -1172
6-Jan-18     2  -561    3220    -2147   -3635
7-Jan-18     2  1201    -2889   -2430   -2087
8-Jan-18     2  -3730   -1774   -2562   -3909
9-Jan-18     2  -3122   1169    345     -3254
10-Jan-18    2  -2879   1898    3959    -3631
11-Jan-18    2  2895    -961    -2610   -3705
12-Jan-18    2  -2372   -1190   -1106   3437
13-Jan-18    2  -3228   -1263   1775    3179
14-Jan-18    2  -1033   1609    -2656   -542
15-Jan-18    2  -3767   1288    1590    -231
16-Jan-18    2  -1502   -3784   426     232
17-Jan-18    2  -2252   1267    -1219   -2817
18-Jan-18    2  -3943   -3779   2186    2529
19-Jan-18    2  342     2301    550     375
20-Jan-18    2  909    -1235    391     -41
1-Jan-18     3  2762    -3361   -3421   2421
2-Jan-18     3  1373    3209    2994    435
3-Jan-18     3  -190    -3903   1428    3135
4-Jan-18     3  -2931   3675    -3869   992
5-Jan-18     3  821    -2150    3789    899
6-Jan-18     3  1461    -227    -2912   3066
7-Jan-18     3  962     3370    2137    -2894
8-Jan-18     3  -1771   -3644   -3204   1890
9-Jan-18     3  -3368   -2984   2837    1024
10-Jan-18    3  92      2562    -2232   856
11-Jan-18    3  3081    2613    -3584   2076
12-Jan-18    3  968     -1805   1970    -537
13-Jan-18    3  -3652   -3626   -902    3261
14-Jan-18    3  -836    -1907   -3678   -2136
15-Jan-18    3  3875    -2149   -3630   -3768
16-Jan-18    3  -1953   3333    971     1912
17-Jan-18    3  3559    2634    -1480   3697
18-Jan-18    3  -271    -2888   -1727   -2409
19-Jan-18    3  871     2344    3086    1301
20-Jan-18    3  -521    563    -106     993
```

Here is the code that you can run which will produce in sample prediction:

```
#script to run regression with in sample predictors
start_time <- Sys.time()
test = TESTDATA
df_list=split(test, test$Key)
reg_results2 = lapply(df_list,function(temp) {

  good_cols=sapply(temp,function(x){
    is.numeric(x) && ((max(x)-min(x))!=0)
  })

  temp=temp[,good_cols]
  fit=lm(NY~.,data=temp)
  return(fit)
})


reg_predict2 = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
  data.frame(data, pred=predict(model, data))
}, df_list, reg_results2)),c(contains("Key"), contains("Dates"), contains("NY"), contains("pred")))

reg_predict2$difference = reg_predict2$pred - reg_predict2$NY

df_list_summary = lapply(reg_results2, function(model_output){
  broom::tidy(model_output)
})
```

I am trying to edit this line to produce out of sample and be selective of which regression I want to select out of both lists to match.

```
 reg_predict2 = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
      data.frame(data, pred=predict(model, data))
    }, df_list, reg_results2)),c(contains("Key"), contains("Dates"), contains("NY"), contains("pred")))
```

For example:

```
 reg_predict2 = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
          data.frame(data, pred=predict(model, data))
        }, df_list$`1`, reg_results2$`1`)),c(contains("Key"), contains("Dates"), contains("NY"), contains("pred")))
```

Comment: @g3lo can you show how your list and data looks like? It's hard to decipher otherwise.

Comment: @g3lo the problem is, the predict isn't able to get the model. All it gets is a numeric value.

Comment: @YOLO let me know if the edited OP is helpful

Comment: @YOLO essentially I am trying to point the code to match the proper regression equation with the proper data set. Both are in a list, and the match comes from the list name. To simplify, say each list (df_list and reg_results2) has a list of 10 items, numbered 1 to 10. I am trying to say do a prediction for, say list name 3 data and list name 3 regression equation.

Comment: I understood your problem, but without exact data information it's hard for me to test the solution. Provide a minimal example. For now, I see you are subsetting the list incorrectly, so you can try replacing df_list$1 with `df_list[[i]]` and reg_results2$i with `reg_results2[[i]]`

Comment: @YOLO I tried putting those brackets around the `i` but obtain the same error. I wouldn't have expected it to work, since I even tried df_list$1 and reg_results2$1 to see if the idea would work with one, and it doesnt.

How would you recommend I provide a simplified example? I am happy to.

Comment: @YOLO I have edited the OP to reflect a simplified example that you can reproduce and attached a code that will provide you with the df_list as well as reg_results2 list.

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173488/discussion-between-g3lo-and-yolo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, here's a minimal example I've tried to create to address your problem.

```
# create data (this could be your out of sample data)
d1 <- data.frame(weight = c(23,78,98,50), height=c(50,170,190,150))
d2 <- data.frame(weight = c(13,58,78,90), height=c(20,140,172,200))

# these are trained model
p1 <- lm(height ~ weight, data = d1)
p2 <- lm(height ~ weight, data = d2)

# create separate list for out of sample data and models
data_list <- list(d1,d2)
model_list <- list(p1,p2)

# here we will save predictions
oof_predictions = list()

# loop through both the list and predict
for(i in seq(data_list)){

  g <- predict(model_list[[i]], data_list[[i]])
  oof_predictions[[i]] <- g

}

print(oof_predictions)

[[1]]
       1         2         3         4 
70.81604 167.76172 203.01469 118.40755 

[[2]]
       1         2         3         4 
24.05383 128.92180 175.52979 203.49458
```

**Update:** After discussion on chat:-

```
oof_predictions_df = data.frame() 

for(i in seq(df_list)){ 
    g <- predict(reg_results2[[i]], df_list[[i]]) 
    f = data.frame(Key = df_list[[i]][,'Key'], Date = df_list[[i]][,'Dates'], NY = df_list[[i]][,'NY'], pred = g) 
    oof_predictions_df <- rbind(oof_predictions_df, f) 

}
```

Comment: would I paste the prediction part of the code into my existing one? I think my list is a bit different. I have posted a reproducible example for reference in OP.

Comment: Yes, just update the data_list and model_list according to your requirement. And the prediction code should work.

Comment: So i am removing this line of code:

`for(i in seq(df_list)){
reg_predict2 = select(dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(data, model) {
  data.frame(data, pred=predict(model, data))
}, df_list[[i]], reg_results2[[i]])),c(contains("Key"), contains("Dates"), contains("NY"), contains("pred")))
}`

and replacing it with this:
`g <- predict(model_list[[i]], data_list[[i]])
  oof_predictions[[i]] <- g`

Comment: please update your answer to this and I will accept it as an answer. Thank you for all your help!

`oof_predictions_df = data.frame() 


for(i in seq(df_list)){ 
  
  g <- predict(reg_results2[[i]], df_list[[i]]) 
  f = data.frame(Key = df_list[[i]][,'Key'], Date = df_list[[i]][,'Dates'], NY = df_list[[i]][,'NY'], pred = g)
  oof_predictions_df <- rbind(oof_predictions_df, f)
  
}`

Comment: Thank you very much @YOLO, you were very helpful

Comment: are you able to assist me again with the updated code. I tried running out of sample and it gave me this error:

`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'carvar2' not found`

Comment: I presume this is the case because that particular variable is not part of the original model. Maybe we have to input a line within the code to skip the ones that don't exist? Kind of like an if error in excel? Would you know how to fix this?